# AsyncStorage : react-native - getItem()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, asyncstorage

How can I execute what `Async.getItem()` does , using pouchDB in a react.js app?? Need some examples.

Comment: Are you looking for [pouchdb-react-native](https://github.com/stockulus/pouchdb-react-native#readme)?

Comment: @FabianSchultz No I am not, there is no react native in the project.

Comment: Then you can just use pouchDB, there shouldn't be anything special for using it with React. Check out [their documentation](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#fetch_document) or [their guides](https://pouchdb.com/guides/updating-deleting.html).

Answer (score 1):

I got confused! In this title you mention react-native. But, the comment above you said: "there is no react native in the project". Are you NOT using React Native in your Project? Because, AsyncStorage is for React Native. Maybe you are looking for Local Storage or Session Storage that are used for ReactJS, instead.